# Scanner NextLine Method Never Ready While YoutubeDL Process Running?

Tags: java, process, io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to download a Youtube video using YoutubeDL (This isn't necessarily relevant, the process runs and downloads the video).

The real problem is occurring when I set up a scanner to try and read the output from the thread and try to display an ETA (Which is displayed in the youtube-dl process).

```
@Override
public boolean recieveTransmission() throws IOException {
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("youtube-dl", "-f", "best", "--newline", "-o", getPath().toString(), this.url).inheritIO().start();
    try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream())) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            var str = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(str);
            //Check that we're on the right line that contains the ETA and percent
            if (str.contains("[download]") && str.contains("%") && str.contains("ETA")) {
                //Set Progress & ETA
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?%");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
                this.progress = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group().replace("%", ""));
                pattern = Pattern.compile("/d/d:/d/d");
                matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
                this.ETA = matcher.group();
                System.out.println("F");
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Progress: " + this.progress + " ETA: " + this.ETA);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(YoutubeUplink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(StellarDiskManager.getOutputFolder().toAbsolutePath().toString());
    return true;
}
```

What happens instead is that the while loop in never entered into (from my tests in the debugger) indicating that the scanner.hasNextLine method is never true. I'm not sure what is happening with that.

I've made a short video showing what happens. (https://youtu.be/qPKu-ykTo2A)

Just for clarity, the `youtube-dl` process outputs lines like this when downloading using `--newline`: `[download]   1.2% of 41.17MiB at  1.69MiB/s ETA 00:24`